# Is there a documentation browser for Python as nice as railsapi.com

Tags: python

I find the [official Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/) a nightmare to navigate, but I love [railsapi](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.8rc1/).  Does anyone know of a browser for the Python standard library documentation with similar features to railsapi?  Specifically the class browser sidebar and realtime search.

EDIT: I'm familiar with pydoc and it's not really much of an improvement over the online docs, IMO.

Comment: "a nightmare to navigate" is subjective and argumentative.  The rest of the question isn't quite so insulting.  You might want to reconsider the subjective and argumentative part of your question and focus on *specific*, *tangible*, *detailed* problems you're actually having with the documentation.  A vague, broad complaint like that makes your question hard to read.

Comment: It is completely subjective, which is why I prefaced it with "I find".

Comment: Clearly.  Thanks for repeating that.  You might want to reconsider the subjective and argumentative part of your question and focus on specific, tangible, detailed problems you're actually having with the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[iPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/), an interactive Python shell replacement (read: enhancement), includes the `??` operator, which gives you a convenient printout of the pydoc information.

For example:

```
In [5]: eval??
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
Base Class: <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
String Form:    <built-in function eval>
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring [source file open failed]:
    eval(source[, globals[, locals]]) -> value

    Evaluate the source in the context of globals and locals.
    The source may be a string representing a Python expression
    or a code object as returned by compile().
    The globals must be a dictionary and locals can be any mapping,
    defaulting to the current globals and locals.
    If only globals is given, locals defaults to it.
```

Might not be *exactly* what you're looking for, but it's a great way to interact with Python's documentations.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about that.  Of course, that only works if you already know what you're looking for. :)

Comment: True. I do have to agree that searching pydocs is often (always) a pain.

Comment: Just got a downvote for some reason... Wish they had told me why :(

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an awesome documentation browser for Python, Django, JavaScript, iOS etc called [Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash/). It is only for OS X. You can download it from the Mac App Store. If you have a Mac then you'll love it.

Answer (score 2):

There is also an open-source cross-platform alternative to dash: **[Zeal](http://zealdocs.org/)**

It works with a global shortcut (Alt+Space), has instant search, supports many documentation formats and libraries (django, numpy, scipy, six, ...) and other languages.

Answer (score 0):

I like [pdoc](https://github.com/BurntSushi/pdoc). If you install pygments, it will even provide syntax highlighting. Just run it via `pdoc --http` and open `localhost:8080` in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

https://devdocs.io/python seems like a good option as well.

Source: Found by ejp's response on [this Hacker News item](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7978702)